# Easy theming of admin-side forms?

Tags: forms, theming

I need to provide a backend user with a fieldset to enter technical data, such as value (in an editfield) and unit (selected from a dropbox). Instead of the default row-based layout such as in:

```
Value: [editfield]
Unit: {dropbox|values}
```

I would like to provide:

```
Parameter name: [value editfield] {unit|list}
```

While I know I could set up a suggestion template for that, does anyone know of the easiest way to re-position the fields? Display Suite?

Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Arrange Fields](http://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) module.

> This module lets you drag-and-drop the fields of any CCK content type, Webform, or almost any other form in Drupal into the positions you would like for editing. This makes it super simple to have forms with inline fields, which you can change at any point.